# End User Style Testing of asp.net mvc web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, bdd

I am using this default [project](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) of `asp.net web API` . Now I want to create a `BDD style End User testing` .

I want to consume my web API as my real user will do in BDD way using `specflow` . I searched almost 30 hours on google but didn't find any solution . So need any type of help for this purpose .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special tool for writing Web API BDD tests as simply using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) along with SpecFlow is more than easy. Just create a new instance of HttpClient per test and exercise your API as in:

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/api/resource");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You can always wrap this in a reusable function with URI as the parameter and use it in your BDD descriptions. It's very much up to you on how you go on from here.

Comment: I just saw your answer and i did exactky in the sane way . Thanjs alot